# Custom Plugin in Go for KrakenD

Tags: go, plugins, goland, krakend

Know anyone which function i have to use in Go for my plugin to inject a custom header for each incoming request to Gateway Krakend ????

Thanks !!!

i have create a plugin with this function to inject a custom header into for each incoming request in krakenD but it didn't work!!! :

```
return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request){
                   .
                   .
     w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, you are trying to add a header to the response (w), not the request.

KrakenD (actually lura) by default ignores the response headers when a response encoding is used (i.e. anything other than no-op). So I am afraid it is not possible to add a custom header to the response.

See https://github.com/luraproject/lura/issues/311

Comment: It was my false, I wanted to add header in the request